# Select only One row of table by using radio button

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, wrapper-class, selectradio

I want to select only One row of table using apex:selectRadio.. please share some code or helping link if any.. Thank You..
when i click or check one radio button other should be unchecked according to my requirements ..

[image: VF page]

### Apex Controller

```
public class table
{
    public list  emp;
    public table()
    {
        emp= [select id, name from employ__c ];
    }
    public list emp_p
    {
        get
        {
            return emp;
        }
    }
}
```

### VF Page

```
 <apex:page controller="table">  
 <apex:form>
 <apex:pageBlock>
 <apex:pageblockTable value="{!emp_p}" var="e">
 <apex:column headerValue="select">
 <apex:selectRadio>
 </apex:selectRadio>
 </apex:column>
 <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!e.name}"/>
 </apex:pageblockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: Have you already tried anything ? You're far more likely to get helpful answers if you put more effort into a question. Explain what you are trying to do, what you have tried and specificly is blocking you or what you have trouble understanding. The better others understand your question, the better they'll be able to help.

Comment: Please can you provide your source code? - It could be as simple as appending `Limit 1` to your SOQL query.

Comment: @www__c i've edited my post .. now please have a look..

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke sorry now i edited my post can u please help me now ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace :

```
<apex:selectRadio>
 </apex:selectRadio>
```

by :

**VF page :**

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!e.name}" styleClass="myChk" onclick="changeValue(this)">
</apex:selectRadio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeValue(radioButton) {
        var chk = document.getElementsByClassName('myChk');

        for (var i=0; i<chk.length; i++) {
            if(radioButton.value == chk[i].value) {
                chk[i].checked = true;
            } else {
                chk[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In this example, I assume the `Name` is unique. If it's not the case, change this to have a unique reference for each item.

Comment: by replacing it now i have two radio button in single row.. i need only one radio button in each row by selecting one radio button others should be unchecked..

Comment: Ah, ok, i see. Check my updated answer.

Comment: still the same issue i can select more than one rows .. :(

Comment: Did you put an unique value as describe in the answer ? And I replace the `onchange` event by `onclick`. Does it change something ?

Comment: yes .. and i also try html-class instead of styleclass ... by using html-class and onchange when i click on one radio button all buttons are checked..

Comment: I replaced `onchange` by `onclick.`

Comment: still same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20755/discussion-between-sfdc-and-sf-user).

Comment: Do you have answer for this?Please update the Answer